# Is there a test for tractability of nonlinear differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving, nonlinear-system

After lengthy attempts at tackling the problem one might say that coming up with a closed form solution for a nonlinear differential equation is not possible - that the problem is intractable. But is there a more direct, universal way to determine if a problem is intractable or not?